# restart Function in visual C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

I have a windows application I need to create a button that unload/close/restart the currunt form while its running and reload/reopen/restart the same form.

How ??
I tried the hide show thing but it keeps the old form running in the background

Answer (score 4):

```
Application.Restart();
```

I found it ....

Answer (score 0):

`Application.Restart()` will restart your entire application.

`Hide()` will only do what it says, hide the form. If you just want a fresh version of your form to reappear, you can just create a new one, `Show()` it, and `Close()` your current form.

```
public void Restart()
{
  var window = new MyForm();
  window.Show();

  this.Close();
}
```

You'll have 2 forms open for a very short time, so if you have any data connections that need to be closed, do so before reopening the form. To the end-user, it will happen so fast that they won't know 2 forms were open.